# Switch default gateway with route command

Tags: networking, routing, fedora

My laptop is connected to two networks, WiFi and Ethernet. These are two completely separate subnets. The ethernet connection is a development router that I'm working on. At the start of the day when I connect everything, I have a script that sets up the route so that I can connect to the ethernet device correctly, without this it doesn't work. This is a simple little `route add 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s20u3u1` script.

Sometimes, I'd like to be able to route all of my traffic through this device. It'd be very convenient to have a single command to switch over, but as easy as this should be it's not working for me.

I disconnected the WiFi and used `route add default gw 192.168.1.1` to create the new default route.  It's not working.

```
✔ ~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 enp0s20u3u1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s20u3u1
192.168.1.2     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    102    0        0 enp0s20u3u1
192.168.124.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
192.168.200.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 docker0
✔ ~$ ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
✘-2 ~$ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.31 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.684 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.684/1.000/1.317/0.318 ms
✔ ~$ ssh admin@192.168.1.1 ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=56 time=7.621 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=1 ttl=56 time=4.963 ms
^CKilled by signal 2.
✘-255 ~$
```

I'm convinced this is a routing problem because this does work:

```
$ route add 8.8.8.8 gw 192.168.1.1
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=56 time=8.323 ms
```

Why is the kernel networking stack ignoring the default route I've created? Does it have the wrong flags, metric, ref? Googling this problem is difficult because there are a million questions with this symptom where the user just doesn't have a default gateway setup.

Comment: The `genmask` should be `0.0.0.0` as well. Not sure why it's not, as it looks like your command is right.